# Eclipse Link Multitenant JSF/EJB/JPA app

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to implement multitenancy with the Table per tenant/Schema strategy in a JPA/EclipseLink/EJB3/JSF 2.2 application.

The test I'm working on is against a mysql app (where 3 databases have been created) a system datatbase common to all tenants, and same database for each tenant.

The system database is only havin one table tenant_user (login, pasword, schema_name)

Here are snippets on the main code :
Login bean (JSF managed bean):

```
public void loginUser(){
        UserTenant userTenant = systemFacade.getUserTenantByUserDetails(login, password);
        System.out.println("User " + userTenant.getLogin() + " got connected ..");
        emProvider.getEm(userTenant.getSchemaName());
        achatFacade.setTenantId(userTenant.getSchemaName());
        Achat achat = new Achat();
        achat.setName("new achat");
        achatFacade.create(achat);
    }


@EJB
    private IEntityManagerProvider emProvider;

    @EJB
    private SystemFacadeLocal systemFacade;

    @EJB
    private AchatFacadeLocal achatFacade;
```

EntityManagerProvider

```
    @Singleton
    public class EntityManagerProvider implements IEntityManagerProvider {

        @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "multi")
        private EntityManagerFactory emf;

        private final Map<String, EntityManager> emMap = new HashMap<>();

        public EntityManager getEm(String tenantId) {
            if (emMap.containsKey(tenantId)) {
                return emMap.get(tenantId);
            }
            return createEm(tenantId);

        }

private EntityManager createEm(String tenantId) {

        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put("eclipselink.tenant-id", tenantId);
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(props);
        emMap.put(tenantId, em);
        return em;

    }
```

AchatFacade:

```
@Stateless
public class AchatFacade extends AbstractFacade implements AchatFacadeLocal {

    @EJB
    IEntityManagerProvider emProvider;

    @Resource
    SessionContext context;

    private String tenantId;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emProvider.getEm(tenantId);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

}
```

My persistence unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="systemPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/si_system</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="multi" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/multi</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In my JSF managed bean, I am retrieving the user tenant from the user_tenant table and I'm setting the tenantId which is the schema name in the EntityManagerProvider.
I'm also creating an EntityManager with the corresponding tenant id in the EntityManagerProvider which is a Singleton EJB. As a result I have a map of EntityManagers.
And finally I'm testing a persist on a multitenant entity which is Achat:

```
package com.intercom.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Multitenant;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.MultitenantType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.TenantTableDiscriminator;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.TenantTableDiscriminatorType;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "achat")
@XmlRootElement
@Multitenant(value = MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA, contextProperty = "eclipselink.tenant-id")
public class Achat implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Achat)) {
            return false;
        }
        Achat other = (Achat) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.intercom.itManager.entities.Achat[ id =" + id + " ]";
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Result of the test:
The user gets connected following its login and password.
tenant is resolved
entity manager is created, map is populated.
the persist on the Achat entity is reached but nothing gets saved in any tenant database.

What code could have caused the problem?

Comment: You haven't shown how you are persisting or committing your transaction, or anything to do with the transaction.  Try calling flush, as it will throw an exception immediately if the Persistence unit isn't joined to a transaction.

Comment: Well, I was thinking I could use Container managed Entity managers, but in a multi-tenant app, I had to create my entity managers myself (EntityManagerProvide code) so I had to open a transaction myself and comit it. Fine for now, I'll use BMT with my custom entity managers.

Comment: But is there a way to share the tenantId between all EJBs? I don't want to pass the tenantId whenever I want to, from my JSF Managed Beans to EJBs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. It would be nice to see some logs. By the way, your logging configuration in persistence.xml is incorrect. Possibly you copied it from Hibernate persistence unit. It has to be something like this instead:

```
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>
```